# How to parse HTML JSON String

Tags: objective-c, webview

I am troubling to parse JSON from Html String, Please suggest me better way to parse.

```
<html><head></head><body>{"data":{"type":"success","message":"Thanks for order with XYZ."}}</body></html>
```

This Html string response  from `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` API.

I want to parse "type" and "message" from above string. I am not getting expected result from `rangeOfString` API.

Thanks in advances.

Comment: Get rid first of `<html><head></head><body>` and `</body></html>`, then use `NSJSONSerialization` on the rest.

Comment: Clarify your last sentence. What use of `rangeOfString` are you talking about? Update your question with actual code showing what you are doing and clearly indicate what issues you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need this as a dictionary in Obj-C:

```
NSString * html = @"<html><head></head><body>{\"data\":{\"type\":\"success\",\"message\":\"Thanks for order with XYZ.\"}}</body></html>";
NSData * data = [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSAttributedString * attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:data documentAttributes:nil];
NSData * jsonData = [attributedString.string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary * result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"Output %@",result);
```

Comment: That's really inefficient but kind of clever.

Comment: Well, the most inefficient part is, that the JSON seems to be wrapped into html for no obvious reason. You can also use NSScanner to extract the body.